# How does modulation affect RF power measurement?

Tags: amplifier, rf, modulation

I'm working on a ground station for cubesats and I have a question about the protection circuitry I'm designing. The amplifier I'm using is the 1094 amplifier from empowerrf which can be seen [here](https://www.empowerrf.com/products/display_amplifier.php?sku=1094).

The only parameters important for this question are that the amplifier lists a drive level for the listed output power of 0 dBm and a damage level of +10 dBm. In order to protect the amplifier in case a user tries to set the input power too high, I am using a directional coupler which feeds a RF power detector such as the AD8314. This way, I can determine the power that is going into the amplifier and turn it off if it was too high.

However, the AD8314 mentions that the measurement is only valid without corrections for a sinusoidal (CW) signal. The data sheet says that if "a true power (waveform independent) response is needed, the use of an rms-responding detector, such as the AD8361, should be considered)".

I will be using GFSK modulation for my system at first. As far as I understand, since only the frequency of the carrier is shifted, not the amplitude, **will the measured power output of the AD8314 stay the same between a pure sine tone and a GFSK modulated sine?** If I move to BPSK and QPSK modulation, I assume that the output of the AD8314 will not accurately reflect the power in the waveform and the AD8361 will be needed. But then, if the measured power of the AD8361 reports +10 dBm, **is this the same type of measurement that the damage level on the amplifier is listed as?** I assume the input damage level was a CW measurement, **how do we compare the energy in a modulated signal to this damage level?**

One more thing, with an SDR that is producing these signals, if I use the same gain setting on the output, **will GFSK have a higher signal power versus a pulse-shaped QPSK signal due to the zero crossings present in the pulse-shaped QPSK?**